# Alignment issue for TextView

Tags: android

I am displaying the `TextView` within a `RelativeLayout`.

I want to put the `TextView` at the center of the Layout.

Within the layout xml,
for `TextView` am using the property  `android:gravity="center"`  is not working .

I do not want to hard code by using `android:layout_marginLeft` or Right since it can give different effect in portrait or landscape mode.

Is there property so that it looks the same for both landscape & portrait mode & the `TextView` occupies the center of the Layout

Comment: could you post some of the XML, or screen shots of how its not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `RelativeLayout` is your `TextView`'s parent, you simply set `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` on your `TextView`. No other properties are needed.